# Differential form on $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $f:S^2\to\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ be a mapping that takes the point of the unit sphere into a straight line passing through this point and the center of the sphere. Let $r:S^2\to S^2$ be a mapping that takes every point of the sphere to its diametrically opposite point. Let $w$ be a 2-form on $S^2$. Prove that the existence of a 2-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ such that $w=f^*\eta$ is equivalent to $r^*w=w$. ($f^*$ is a pull-back map, in our case $f^*: \Omega^2(\mathbb R\mathbb P^2) \to \Omega^2(S^2)$ )

I don't understand what should I show to prove that 2-form is exist.

Comment: I think the statement should be something like ``given $w$ on $S^2$, show that there exists a $2$-form $\eta$ on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ such that $w=f^\ast \eta$ iff $r^\ast w = w$.''

Comment: @WSL Yes, but how prove the existence of a 2-form?

Comment: Maybe this can be proved with De-Rham cohomology?

Comment: $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Therefore it makes sense to pushforward $\omega$ to a form $\eta$, at least locally. Then use the equivariance condition to establish that this defines $\eta$ globally and unambiguously.

Comment: @AlexProvost What is "equivariance condition"?

Comment: @user1223 I mean the condition $r^* \omega = \omega$. This condition means that $\omega$ acts the same at antipodal points of the sphere as it does on the original points on the sphere, i.e., it is invariant under the antipodal $\mathbb Z/2$ action on the sphere. Such an object that commutes with a group action is called equivariant.

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks, didn't know it. What about "pushforward $w$ to $\eta$"? It means that we should action on $w$ some map $A: w \to \eta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to push the form $\omega$ forward by the local diffeomorphism $f$. By "pushing forward" I really mean pulling back by the inverse. In other words, around any point in the projective plane you can find a small open set $U$ such that there exist two distinct sections $s_1,s_2:U \to S^2$ of the double cover $f$ with $r \circ s_i = s_j$ if $i \neq j$. Now define $\eta = s_1^* \omega$ on the open set $U$. This yields a well-defined global form because the equivariance condition gives us $$s_2^* \omega = (r \circ s_1)^* \omega = s_1^* (r^* \omega) = s_1^*\omega.$$

So even if you picked two distinct sections on two neighbourhoods of a point, the equivariance condition guarantees that the pulled back form $\eta$ agrees on the intersection of the neighbourhoods.